# How to choose which image FB displays?

Tags: html, wordpress, facebook

You may know that when you share a link on Facebook, it selects one/some of the images from the page and you can't really control which image is the thumbnail.

Long story short, I've read that some simple html in my website can help FB determine what image to choose.

We are using WordPress. I actually want to achieve this:

[How do a change the thumbnail image of my link when posting to facebook?](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/how-do-a-change-the-thumbnail-image-of-my-link-when-posting-to-facebook)

I am total beginner in html/wordPress and only helping a friend. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open graph data will allow your chosen content to display on Facebook and Twitter.

http://ogp.me

For an image you would place in the HEAD of your HTML document:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/img/test.jpg" />
```

Comment: How do I add that property the image I want but in WordPress?

Comment: I found it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaFesgaPdTk